# How to remove extraneous object descriptions in xtext index

Tags: java, xtext

In my DSL I customize the index using a DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy class and life is good. I can see my object descriptions as they are created, I can search the index for them and and in non-plugin tests the index contains only those objects exported by my DSL.

When using the UI, however, when I press 'ctr-shft-f3' (open model element) there is, in addition to the objects from my DSL, a ton of 'javafx' names (and only javafx, no other namespaces). When I search the index in UI mode I also find these objects (before my scope providers filter them out). Has anyone any idea what silly thing I may have done to cause this? It's not a huge problem since my filters remove junk anyway but

1. How did I manage to get that crap in there?
2. How to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one Xtext index shared by all plugins, so languages can cross reference each other.

> How did I manage to get that crap in there?

There should be a plugin which contributes it.

> How to get rid of it?

You should find and uninstall this plugin.

Comment: Hi, I have accepted this answer because it is simply just correct. I was using a committer version of eclipse for another project so whatever came with that Ooomph install is the culprit. On other installs they are not there. As a result, I have not found the exact culprit but that is not the issue. As Anton points out, the index is shared so it is not out unexpected to find other entires in the index.